# How to launch the battery applet in ubuntu manually?

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, power

THe The title says it all. :\ i want to know the command to launch it so that i can use it with window managers that don't automatically load it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gnome-power-applet. :| wasn't hard to find.